# Starting Docker for windows takes so much ram even without running a container How to prevent it?

Tags: docker, windows-10

When I start docker for windows memory usage increases by almost 25% of 6 GB (that's 1.5 GB) without even running a container. I can't see the docker process that in the task manager, but I figured the memory usage by looking at the memory usages % before and after running the docker for windows program.
I'm running windows 10. How can I prevent docker from eating up all this ram.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change it in settings. Just decrease memory usage by the slider. Go to settings and choose the Advanced tab.
[image]
other settings:
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#docker-settings-dialog

Comment: Thanks, that  really helped :D

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to create a `.wslconfig` file in the Windows home directory (`C:\Users\<Your Account Name>`).

Input the contents of the file as follows:-

```
[wsl2]
memory=1GB
processors=1
```

The memory and processors are the resources allocated to the wsl2 process. You can change the memory and processors according to your preference. This is my config on a 16GB i5 machine.

After that, restart the WSL2 process:-

Start PowerShell in admin mode and type: `Restart-Service LxssManager`

After that, you are good to go!

P.s.: Start docker only when it is required.